# Split audio file (mp3, wav, wma) into 1s chunks

Tags: java, file, audio, split, analysis

I am getting the FFT back on an audio file, but it doesn't take into account the time in the song that that frequency occurred. I first tried getting the length of the file, and then spreading the FFT results equally over the track length, but that might be wrong and not give the correct frequencies back. So now I am trying to get the file split up into 1 second chunks and then return the frequency for that second alone, and then I will store that in a  database to save it.

But I have no clue on how to save it, all other threads I have found and research I have done only shows how to break into x amount of parts, not per second as in a song. Is there a way to do this?

Sorry if this is a trivial topic, but I am very new to Java and programming, so this is quite a struggle for me.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code so far:

```
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    float durationInSeconds = 0;  
    Tag tag; 
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.jaudiotagger").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    AudioFile audioFile;
    try {
        audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
        System.out.println("Track length = " + audioFile.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength());
        durationInSeconds = audioFile.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength();
    } catch (CannotReadException | TagException | ReadOnlyFileException
            | InvalidAudioFrameException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        convert();
        System.out.println(((durationInSeconds)/endResult.length)*1000);
        for(int i = 0; i < endResult.length; i++) {

            Thread.sleep((long) (((durationInSeconds)/endResult.length)*1000));
            System.out.println(endResult[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I know this doesn't address your problem directly but typical technique is to divide into 2^n samples chunks and process; possibly with overlapping blocks, possibly applying a window function (Google it) depending on desired frequency response. If you are modifying the FFT and applying an inverse you *will* want overlapping blocks, cross-faded in output, because you will get audible clicks between blocks if the apparent phase (or the 0Hz constant term) changes. BTW, frequency (Hz) is index * sample_rate / block_size.

Comment: What are you having trouble with specifically? The code you've shown is I guess using Entagged which only reads meta data. So it's not relevant to what you're wanting to do. Are you already reading sample data somewhere? Using a specific library? Just trying to narrow the question down a little. Covering all steps from start to finish would be a very long answer.

Comment: I consolidated my previous comments in to one. Would like to help, the question is just too general to tell what answer you need at the moment. Details like what library you're using, what classes, etc, are important.

Comment: What it does there is it gets the song's fft and plays it back over the length of the song. I am using the FFT algorithm from the Columbus University (google fft). And to get the length of the track I am using `JAudioTagger`

Comment: An FFT will generate at least as much data as the original samples - and more if you use overlapping windows.  I assume you are storing this in a database in order to perform some kind of analysis or retrieval. If this is the case, what you probably need is some kind of audio feature extraction